# Cannot find 'make' program error when trying to build Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

After upgrading the OS X to Lion, i started to receive the following error when trying to build my Android app form Eclipse:

/Android/android-ndk-r6-crystax-2/ndk-build 
ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possible have some paths not set correctly. I had an error when upgrading too, but I decided to delete my old eclipse and do a fresh download from the website which seemed to fix it. Also, make sure the latest updates for Mac OS X 10.7 is installed. Best of luck!

Oh, almost forgot. Goto the ADK manager in eclipse and make sure there is no updates available for that either.